# NextJs and uikit framework: Prop className did not match

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getuikit

I'm using [uikit framework](https://getuikit.com/) in my next.js project.

In this HTML code:

```
<div className="uk-child-width-1-2@m" data-uk-grid>...</div>
```

It gives this error:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match.
Server: "uk-child-width-1-2@m uk-grid uk-grid-stack"
Client: "uk-child-width-1-2@m"
```

In fact, the `data-uk-grid` adds 2 classes (`uk-grid` and `uk-grid-stack`) to the element by its js. So there is a difference in the list of classes in Server and Client (due to server side rendering), and Nextjs gives this error.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: how did you import uikit in your project?

Comment: @mocherfaoui npm i uikit , then import js and css in _app.tsx

Comment: did you use `async` attribute for `script` tag? if yes change it to `defer`

Comment: @mocherfaoui I don't use `<script>`  tag. I used `import` in the _app.tsx file.

Comment: can you try to add them using the `<script>` tag in `_document`'s `<Head>` with `defer` attribute?

Comment: @mocherfaoui I tried this too, but there is still same problem.

Comment: maybe uikit doesn't support SSR? can you update your question and include code snippets of how you imported uikit and its scripts?